# OverScroll animation on activity

Tags: android, imageview, overscroll

I have an imageView on my activity and I implemented a fling gesture on it to change the image from a list og images, but i want to add an overscroll animation to my activity when it reach the end (or beginning) of the list any pointer on how to implement this, google is not helping

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work has already been done for you in [this project](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh). Look at the code for [RotateLoadingLayout](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh/blob/master/library/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/internal/RotateLoadingLayout.java). Your class would look very similar, but substitute your own Animation where you see mRotateAnimation.